# Proxy Socket Managing

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to create a transparent proxy with c#. i was able to transfer my network traffic into my proxy client and redirect it to my proxy server. it's working, but i have 2 problems,

1- It's slow, max speed is 60kbps, here is how i transfer traffic between my server and proxy client

```
while (SocketConnected(tcp_link.Client) && 
       SocketConnected(_tcp.Client) && 
       !ioError)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        if (streamLink.DataAvailable)
        {
            byte[] l_buffer = new byte[4096];
            int l_read = streamLink.Read(l_buffer, 0, l_buffer.Length);
            byte[] l_data = new byte[l_read];
            Array.Copy(l_buffer, l_data, l_data.Length);

            byte[] l_send = MBR.reverse(l_data);

            _stream.Write(l_send, 0, l_send.Length);
        }

        if (_stream.DataAvailable)
        {
            byte[] c_buffer = new byte[4596];
            int c_read = _stream.Read(c_buffer, 0, c_buffer.Length);
            byte[] c_data = new byte[c_read];
            Array.Copy(c_buffer, c_data, c_data.Length);

            byte[] c_send = MBR.reverse(c_data);

            streamLink.Write(c_send, 0, c_send.Length);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        onErrorLog(this, new ErrorLogEventArgs(ex));
        ioError = true;
    }
}
```

my other question is: when should i close my socket? and which one should get closed first? is http server going to close connection with my proxy server or i should disconnect?

sorry for my back english

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't use the Begin... and End... pattern of the [Socket class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/600stss7.aspx)? If you refactor to those you can get rid of the Thread.Sleep(1) causing a delay anyway.

Comment: i did that too, no change in speed even worse

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a problem with mere logic but rather about handling the parallelism. I have used [SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx) for implementing a high performance, async TCP server and it shines.

A good article can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod).